# Docker run command, volumes error when using relative paths

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a docker run and build command out of the compose file below.

So far I have come up with this:

```
docker build --tag testenvironment/nodejs ./node_js
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ./node_js:/home/app/chat -v /home/app/chat/node_modules --name nodejs testenvironment/nodejs
```

I'm stuck here because it gives the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: create ./node_js: "./node_js" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intented to pass a host directory, use absolute path. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

**Compose file:**

```
node:
  build: ./node_js
  command: node server.js
  depends_on:
    - mongo
  links:
    - mongo      
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: development  
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  volumes:
    - ./node_js:/home/app/chat
    - /home/app/chat/node_modules
```

Can anybody tell me how to convert the volumes from the compose file to a docker run command? Thanks in advance.

I am using the Docker Toolbox for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an absolute path when adding a volume in Windows, which can be in the following formats:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v //c/users/desktop/path/to/node_js:/home/app/chat
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v C://users/desktop/path/to/node_js:/home/app/chat
```

Answer (score 3):

This part:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ./node_js:/home/app/chat ....
```

Should be:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd)/node_js:/home/app/chat
```

`docker run` requires an absolute path for volumes (as a difference from compose)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your solution but it didn't work. It may be notable that I am using Docker Toolbox for windows. I got the following error: `Error parsing reference: "/node_js:/home/app/chat" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.`

Comment: I did that with the same result: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd)/node_js:/home/app/chat -v /home/app/chat/node_modules --name nodejs testenvironment/nodejs`

Comment: Same error message? `includes invalid characters for a local volume name`?

Comment: @Jan The `$(pwd)` syntax is a shell feature that may not exist depending on what prompt you are running on windows. Either type the full path, or use `docker-compose up` since you have a compose yml.

Comment: @Robert i got this error: `Error parsing reference: "/node_js:/home/app/chat" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.`

Comment: @BMitch using pwd on its own works. Using the full path would work, but a pwd-like option would be better since the docker environment has to work anywhere. Docker compose does not run on the server where the environment has to be

Comment: @Jan since `$(pwd)` is a shell command, not a docker command, if you need the same command to work everywhere, you'll want to run the same shell everywhere. There are options to run bash on Windows.